# return one value in fetch row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, row, fetch

i have a fetch row query that returns

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

however, i only want to return the last value, which is "1" in this case.

i tried to do `echo row[0][9]` but it doesn't work.
how do i get the last value?

Comment: Not to mention the SQL statements. [Questions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) should always have [minimal sample code](http://sscce.org/) to make them more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `end()` function

```
$row = array(10, 9, 8, 7);
echo end($row); // displays 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
?>
```

Take a look @ this example. Copied from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php). You should be able to achieve what you wanted by taking a look at the above example.

If you know what the column index is, you are good to go. But if you ALWAYS want the last column take a look at the [mysql_num_fields](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo explode(' ', $row[0])[9]`

Been a while since I've done PHP though, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

you must sort your table by `DESC` keyword .

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it all on MySQL side, so you don't split the logic between PHP and MySQL too much (if that's applicable in this case) and use query with `LIMIT 1` and `ORDER BY DESC` (or ASC, depending on your table).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code.

```
$query="SELECT blog_id FROM myblogs_view where blog_id<'$id' ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result) or die(mysql_error())) {
    echo $row;
}
```

This returns the values in one row. how do i access the value in the last row only?

Answer (score 0):

You only want the 10th last row that was added to the table? That would be the 10th id in the list if you sort by id descending. If that's what you want, you also could tell MySQL to return exactly that row. The query gets a bit more complicated though:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id
  FROM table
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 10
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: His example only returns one row, which is a space separated string of numbers.

Comment: You could be right, in which case my answer doesn't make much sense. Steph should show the code that produces the output and maybe I should wait till that code is available.